# Add a DataRow to a DataTable without the ColumnChanged event firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datatable, datarow

Is there a way to add an existing `DataRow` to a `DataTable` without that `DataTable`'s `ColumnChanged` event being fired?  I have an event handler hooked up to the `ColumnChanged` event that I'd like to continue running for all existing rows in the table, but I don't want it to fire for the new row until the row has been added to the table (I don't want it to fire *while* the row is being added).

I've tried:

```
table.ImportRow(rowToAdd); // causes the ColumnChanged event to fire
```

And

```
DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    newRow[col.ColumnName] = rowToAdd[col.ColumnName]; // causes the ColumnChanged event to fire
table.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

I've figured out a work around where I store the row currently being added and check that value in the event handler, but if there was a way to add the row without the event being fired that would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `table.Rows.Add(params Object[] values);` instead. E.g.

```
Object[] values = new Object[table.Columns.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
   values[i] = rowToAdd[table.Columns[i].ColumnName]; // not sure if order is consistent
table.Rows.Add(values);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for.  Unfortunately after trying this though, I found out that someone has hooked up an initialize method to the RowChanged event that computes a number of fields whenever a row has been added to the table (causing the ColumnChanged event to fire)... so in the end it looks like I'll be stuck using my work around anyway.  Still, you're answer is a correct answer to my original question so I'll mark it as so.